# Disable zooming in for photo swipe

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, photo-gallery

I'm using [Photo Swipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/) to display my images. The default behavior when using it is that once the images are clicked, I'll be able to bring me to a "zoom-in page" where the photos are enlarged and i can view them one by one by swiping.

I'm trying to overwrite this behavior because I want to do something else after the user clicks on the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to disable zooming you must set

```
allowUserZoom = false
```

Comment: The `allowUserZoom` doesn't exist in the source of PhotoSwipe 4.

Answer (score 10):

All solutions described here did not work for me. Here is a complete solution that turns off zooming.

Settings:

```
var options = {
    // Gallery options
    maxSpreadZoom: 1,
    getDoubleTapZoom: function (isMouseClick, item) {
        return item.initialZoomLevel;
    },
    // UI options
    zoomEl: false
};
```

Gallery init:

```
var gallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
// ...
```

And finally add this CSS snippet to disable zoom cursor:

```
.pswp--zoom-allowed .pswp__img {
    cursor: default !important
}
```

Comment: As of version 5.4.1 the function has changed slightly
`secondaryZoomLevel: (zoomLevelObject) => { return 'fit' }` [docs here](https://photoswipe.com/adjusting-zoom-level/)

Answer (score 6):

The option `allowUserZoom` doesn't exist in the [documentation](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/options.html) 
You can disable the double tap zoom by returning `item.initialZoomLevel` and reduce the spread (zoom) gesture by setting `maxSpreadZoom` to the same initialZoom :

```
gallery.init();

gallery.options.maxSpreadZoom = gallery.getZoomLevel();
gallery.options.getDoubleTapZoom = function(isMouseClick, item) {
    return item.initialZoomLevel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 version the answer is for example:

```js
imageClickAction: 'next' / 'close',
```

Answer (score 0):

### Updated: PhotoSwipe 5

To adjust opening or closing transition type use lightbox option `showHideAnimationType (String)`.

It supports three values:

1. `zoom` (default)
2. `fade` (default if there is no thumbnail)
3. `none`

Animations are automatically disabled if user `(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)`.

Answer (score 0):

This pure css solutions seems to work for me:

```
.pswp__img {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.pswp__button--zoom {
    display: none !important;
}
```